# How to derive weekdays from query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to I get the weekday name after `OrderH_dtmInitiated` column

```
SELECT 
    Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112) AS BookingDate,   
    --(To derived weekdays name from OrderH_dtmInitiated namely weekdays here)
    [OrderH_strEmailConfirmationSent], [OrderH_strEmail]  
FROM 
    [VISTAIT].[dbo].[tblOrderHistory] 
WHERE  
    OrderH_strEmailConfirmationSent IS NULL 
    AND OrderH_dtmInitiated >= (SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-1)))  
ORDER BY 
    Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`datename`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx):

```
SELECT 
   Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112) As BookingDate,   
   Datename (weekday, OrderH_dtmInitiated) As NameOfDay,
   [OrderH_strEmailConfirmationSent] 
  ,[OrderH_strEmail]  
FROM [VISTAIT].[dbo].[tblOrderHistory] 
WHERE  OrderH_strEmailConfirmationSent is NULL And OrderH_dtmInitiated >= (SELECT  DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()-1)))  
ORDER by Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112)
```

Comment: I change query as above but it s not working anymore

Comment: @EugeneJONG The OP query and this one do not have a `group by` clause. If you have a different question please use a different post to ask it.

Comment: Mureinik, could you assist on the above? the query after I revised its not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112)as datebooking,
  Datename (weekday, OrderH_dtmInitiated) As NameOfDay,
   count(distinct OrderH_strCinemaId)as cinemassite,
   count(distinct OrderH_intID)as TotalBookingMade,   
   SUM(case when OrderH_strEmailConfirmationSent like 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as OrderH_strEmailConfirmationSent,
   SUM(case when OrderH_strEmailConfirmationSent is NULL then 1 else 0 end) as EmailHavingNull   

FROM [VISTAIT].[dbo].[tblOrderHistory]
WHERE OrderH_dtmInitiated >= '2015-05-07'
GROUP BY Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112)
ORDER by Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112)
```

Comment: this happen to have the error "Column 'VISTAIT.dbo.tblOrderHistory.OrderH_dtmInitiated' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: Looking an answer on above qns after I add in Group by clause

Comment: Add the new column to GROUP BY, too

Comment: How to have 2 GROUP BY? don quite understand how to add new statement

Comment: `GROUP BY Convert(char(8), OrderH_dtmInitiated, 112), Datename (weekday, OrderH_dtmInitiated)` or add an aggregate function to NameOfDay: `MIN(Datename (weekday, OrderH_dtmInitiated))  As NameOfDay`